# Search character in String

Tags: python-3.x, string

I am trying to write a function to search for a character within a string. Given a character and string as inputs, the function should return the index of the first occurrence of the character within the string. If the string does not contain the character, the function should return -1.

I am not allowed to use any built-in library functions to answer this question (e.g. not use the find() or index() functions).

I have attempted to answer this with the following code:

```
string = list(input("Enter string/text you would like to use: "))
search = input("Enter character you would like to search: ")

# Main loop that searches for character in string
while True:
    index = -1
    for char in string:
        index = index + 1
        if char == search:
            print(True)
            print(index)
            break
```

However, when running, although using a break, it is caught in a loop. Any suggestions as to how to solve this question?

Comment: Why do you need the `while True`? If you left out the `while` loop it would do as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't even need the while loop:

```
def searchChar(char,string):
    for char in string:
      index += 1
      if char == search:
          return index
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the

`while True:`

The for loop already iterates over your input, so it is not needed.